# AutoHotKey: Run code on Window Event (Close)

Tags: events

I work with a local application which when ESCAPE is pressed, the current window is closed. I wanted to avoid that so I made a script with AutoHotKey that detects the name of the window within the app and, if I press ESCAPE, the window doesn't close (Unless I press the X).

> `#IfWinActive ahk_class name_of_app_class_here`
>
> `Escape::return`

Now I would like to apply a code for when that window is closed (by pressing the X) but I cuoldn't find any solution for that in the forum or in the help.
Example:

> `#IfWinActive ahk_class name_of_app_class_here`
>
> `OnWindowClose`
>
> ```
>   `Do_something`
> ```

Hope it is well explained. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do what you want to achieve:

```
;tested on Notepad (Windows 7)
;note: may not work correctly if aero mode is on
;note: if you click a Notepad window that is *not* the active window, it will be closed
;note: some programs don't return the standard NCHITTEST value for a close button,
;a workaround is to compare the cursor position against the window coordinates

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
LButton::
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
if vWinClass not in Notepad
Return

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, hWnd2

if (hWnd = hWnd2)
{
SendMessage, 0x84, 0, vPosX|(vPosY<<16), , ahk_id %hWnd% ;WM_NCHITTEST
vNCHITTEST := ErrorLevel ;(8 min, 9 max, 20 close)

if (vNCHITTEST = 20)
{
MsgBox can't close me! ;put your code here
Return
}
}

SendInput {LButton Down}
KeyWait, LButton
SendInput {LButton Up}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Note:
The code posted in the link below, achieves something related, catching close buttons for *all* windows, not just for one program, whether they are active or inactive.

[Is it possible to catch the close button and minimize the window instead? AutoHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882844/is-it-possible-to-catch-the-close-button-and-minimize-the-window-instead-autoho/41325497#41325497)