# Is it possible to catch the close button and minimize the window instead? AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want all programs in my computer to be closed only by right clicking the taskbar icon and choosing close. So when I click the X button on any window, it should translate to minimize instead. How can I achieve this using AutoHotKey?

Comment: If only the closing event is needed to be detected, then the script would be more simple. [How to minimize a window by closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53405915/3416774)

Answer (score 4):

This AutoHotkey script should achieve what you're looking for. Note: the code may not work correctly if aero mode is on.

- `MouseGetPos` gets the `hWnd` of the window under the cursor.
- `WM_NCHITTEST` gets information about the type of item under the cursor, needing a bit of fiddly maths to combine the coordinates into a 4-byte structure.

The difficult bit is that every time you use the mouse, this script captures every left mouse button press, but must not interfere with the mouse's normal functioning. When the mouse button is pressed, no presses are sent, the press is suppressed. A check is done on the window below the cursor. If a close button is found, then that window is minimised, and we never actually send a mouse press. If no close button is found we emulate the normal function of the mouse: a down press is sent, until it is detected that the mouse button has been released, and a mouse release is sent. I use the word 'press' because it is a clearer word than 'click' or 'hold' which imply quick/long durations.

This solution is in fact quite simple, but the issue gave me a lot of trouble, some years ago when I first investigated it and tested out different approaches. I have never had the mouse functionality compromised, but I can't guarantee, there isn't some software where it won't work, or would work incorrectly.

If some programs don't return the standard `NCHITTEST` value for a close button, I believe this was true of Winamp 2.5e and previous versions of Mozilla Firefox, then a workaround is to check for the class/exe of the program, and work out if the location under the cursor relative to the window is consistent with the close button.

Btw I use the same principles for my 'minimiser' script that I plan to release in possibly the next few months, where if you right-click the minimise button, it minimises the window to the system tray.

```
;tested on Windows 7
;note: may not work correctly if aero mode is on
;note: some programs don't return the standard NCHITTEST value for a close button,
;a workaround is to compare the cursor position against the window coordinates

LButton::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, hWnd

WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %hWnd%

if vWinClass not in BaseBar,#32768,Shell_TrayWnd,WorkerW,Progman,DV2ControlHost
{
SendMessage, 0x84, 0, vPosX|(vPosY<<16), , ahk_id %hWnd% ;WM_NCHITTEST
vNCHITTEST := ErrorLevel ;(8 min, 9 max, 20 close)
;ToolTip %vNCHITTEST%

if (vNCHITTEST = 20)
{
WinMinimize, ahk_id %hWnd%
Return
}
}

SendInput {LButton Down}
KeyWait, LButton
SendInput {LButton Up}
Return
```

Comment: I cannot fathom a reason for the downvote. The script works EXACTLY as required. Would the downvoter please test the script and state what didn't work.

Comment: Read the article that you posted? Also in WM_NCHITTEST documentation: "If the mouse is not captured, the message is sent to the window beneath the cursor. Otherwise, the message is sent to the window that has captured the mouse".

Comment: And ... so what does that signify that is a problem?
Btw I've had a working minimise/minimise to system tray script, that I wrote in this way, for years, never had a problem, and the other main well-known minimise to system tray utilities and AutoHotkey scripts use WM_NCHITTEST too.

Comment: A WM_NCHITTEST will not necessarily land on the active window, if the active window is not underneath it, that's obvious. Sometimes you want to click the close button on a window that's not in focus.

Comment: Simple: your proposed WM_NCHITTEST solution not work if mouse is captured.

Comment: Please clarify your comment. Are you getting confused with another script?
Anyhow, MouseGetPos establishes the hWnd of the window under the cursor,
and the cursor's coordinates.
Thus when we apply a hit test on the cursor's coordinates, we know
there's going to be a window there, and what it will be.

Comment: -- I've made one code correction. -- Btw: if aero mode is off, and you left-click on a close button, that should *minimise* the window rather than *close* the window. -- Potentially other AutoHotkey scripts with mouse hotkeys could interfere with this one. -- I am going to look into making this script compatible with aero mode. -- Try it in multiple programs such as Notepad, as a small number of programs have unusual handling for pressing the close button (but for which workarounds can be written). -- Best of luck, it should work, the code is good!

Comment: What you talking about Aero? Aero feature was not in Windows XP!!! Problem is that this script disable left click on taskbar, so is impossible restore windows.

Comment: I fixed that, I did a last-minute amendment to the first version of the script, to prevent any chance of minimising important windows, that were not designed to be minimised and could have a weird effect. I have since fixed that bug, the script should be working perfectly now. Yes, I thought Aero wasn't in XP.

Comment: I copy the script to [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/52752/6389) in Software Recommendations, and you may want to check out the [TrayIt!](https://winaero.com/blog/minimize-apps-to-system-tray-notification-area-with-trayit/) program. However, the script interferes with `Capslock::Ctrl`, **even though** I nest it in `#IfWinActive`. I don't know why.

Comment: If only the closing event is needed to be detected, then the script would be more simple. [How to minimize a window by closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53405915/3416774)